# Visual studio extension not loading - Dynamics Finance

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, microsoft-dynamics

I have just installed VS 2019, and downloaded Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.Tools.Installer.vsix from my LCS instance.

The installer runs fine, with no errors.

When I open Visual Studio (as admin), I get the following error. Can anyone help?

[image]